# I want to change the colour of the bars of the hamburger menu into red, it's an image, I'm using angular. Can anyone help, please?

Tags: html, css, angular

```
 <button class="toggle-btn">
    
    <img  src="/assets/hamburger-menu.png">
  
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>  // code for navbar.component.html


.toggle-btn{
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    height:100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:190px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
   
    
}
.toggle-btn > img{

    height: 100%;
```

} // code for css file`enter code here`

I want to change the colour of the bars of the hamburger menu into red, it's an image, I'm using angular. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Could your provide nav bar component HTML and CSS code ?

Comment: You should use this in this website: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CSS [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to change colors of an image.

Here is an example where I colored a hamburger menu to red.

```css
.toggle-btn > .red {
  filter: invert(35%) sepia(97%) saturate(7007%) hue-rotate(339deg) brightness(101%) contrast(95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-btn">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg" />
<div>

<div class="toggle-btn">
  <img class="red" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg" />
<div>
```

You can find a nice code pen to calculate the necessary filters [here](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

---

But I would advise you to check if it is possible to color the original image. The CSS filter function takes up CPU power and will only work if the original image is black.